# Do I need to re-index my site in Google when changing preferred domain?

Tags: google, google-search-console

I have recently changed my site from www.mysite.com to mysite.com and have updated it in Google webmaster tools and .htaccess file. However, to do this I actually had to add mysite.com as a new domain in Google. Does this mean I have to re run the index with Google again and submit a sitemap.xml etc?

Comment: You do not have to do anything- you have already done it. BTW- if you try and hurry Google up, it get's mad. So don't poke the multi-colored bear.

Comment: Your XML sitemap should already contain the canonical non-www URL - yes?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a specific tool for this to help protect your SERP ranking located in the search console. You can find information on changing domains at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en.

The basics are...

1. Complete the actual content migration.
2. Verify the new domain name within the search console.
3. Use the change of address tool in the search console to change address from one domain to another.